# Spearman or Kendall correlation?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I would like to assess the correlation between a 7-category ordinal variable
(X) and a number of other variables some of which are ordinal with 3-6
categories, others are continuous and a couple are dichotomous. The
dataset includes only 24 observations and lack of normality and tied
observations are therefore issues to take into account.

- Would it be best to use the Kendall coefficient to assess the correlation between X and each of the other variables? If so, which one (i.e. tau-a or tau-b; I know that Roger Newson favours the former)?
- Would it be reasonable to use Spearman as well?
- And what would be the best test to assess the correlation with each of the dichotomous variables?

Comment: [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18112/how-does-the-goodman-kruskal-gamma-test-and-the-kendall-tau-or-spearman-rho-test/18136#18136) you might find helpful

Comment: This is very close to this existing question on when to use Spearman versus Kendall http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/kendall-tau-or-spearmans-rho

Answer (score 3):

Rather than either of those I would use Polychoric correlations which were designed for just this instance.  They use maximum likelihood to fit a model an underlying normally distributed continuous variable under each ordinal variable; then calculate the correlation coefficient of the continuous variables.  There are implementations available in R and Stata.