# Correlation coefficients for ordered data: Kendall's Tau vs Polychoric vs Spearman's rho

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, spearman-rho, kendall-tau, polychoric

It seems like for managing with ordered measurements researchers **usually** deal with [Polychoric Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychoric_correlation). (For example, for making matrix before doing Factor Analysis.) Why so?

[Kendall Tau Rank Correlation Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient) and [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) are also suitable for ordered data.

Any points 'pro' and 'contra' for these correlation coefficients are welcome.

Comment: As your Wikipedia link states, the polychoric correlation assumes that the manifest ordinal variables come from categorizing latent normal variables; Kendall's tau & Spearman's correlation do not assume this. Other than that, the differences are covered in [Kendall tau or Spearman's rho?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/) If there is anything left that isn't already covered, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Does it mean that Polychoric is less suitible in general case?

Comment: It means polychoric is appropriate when the manifest ordinal variables came from categorizing latent normal variables & not otherwise. (In practice, it's more like when you are willing to assume this & not otherwise, since you will rarely know & can't really check the assumption.) OTOH, it probably doesn't make much difference in most cases, for an analogy, see my answer here: [difference-between-logit-and-probit-models](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523//30909#30909).

Answer (score 4):

Partially answered in comments:

As your Wikipedia link states, the polychoric correlation assumes that the manifest ordinal variables come from categorizing latent normal variables; Kendall's tau & Spearman's correlation do not assume this. Other than that, the differences are covered in [Kendall Tau or Spearman's rho?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/kendall-tau-or-spearmans-rho) If there is anything left that isn't already covered, please edit to clarify. – gung

(   Does it mean that Polychoric is less suitable in general case? – drobnbobn   )

It means polychoric is appropriate when the manifest ordinal variables came from categorizing latent normal variables & not otherwise. (In practice, it's more like when you are willing to assume this & not otherwise, since you will rarely know & can't really check the assumption.) OTOH, it probably doesn't make much difference in most cases, for an analogy, see my answer here: [Difference between logit and probit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models#30909). – gung