# How do you correlate binary & ordinal variables?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, binary-data

Which test to use to calculate correlations between them?

- Cramer's V,
- Kruskal-Wallis,
- or something else?

Comment: Are you wondering how such correlations are calculated (ie, how to arrive at the number), how they are tested (ie, if they could have come from a population w/o any correlation), or what they mean?

Comment: _italic_ Yes! @gung

Answer (score 3):

Cramér's *V* and the Kruskal–Wallis test are for nominal data; the latter is a null hypothesis test, not a correlation. If you want to calculate the correlation between a dichotomous variable and an ordinal variable, you could use Kendall's $\tau$, the Goodman–Kruskal $\gamma$, or Spearman's $\rho$ (listed in the order in which I'd recommend them, I suppose). If you're estimating population parameters, you can also generate confidence intervals around these statistics or perform null hypothesis tests if you wish.
For some comparisons and a conversion method, see:

- [How do the Goodman-Kruskal gamma and the Kendall tau or Spearman rho correlations compare?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18112/32036)
- [Kendall Tau or Spearman's rho?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3943/32036)

Comment: @user46343: was there anything else you wanted to know, or is my answer [acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/246931)?