# What sort of correlation test is most appropriate in this situation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

The two variables I am testing are:

Indep: Class size

Dep: Performance (like test scores)

The relationship between the variables appears to be nonlinear and the data is interval.

Am I correct in thinking that I should be using a parametric test?

What correlation test would you guys recommend using?

Comment: Are you looking for correlation or a regression function?

Comment: Correlation currently. A regression function could be useful later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look very closely at whether your test scores are truly interval scaled, or merely ordinal. They might be interval, but in the German academic system with grades 1-6 (1-4 is passing), there sometimes seems to be a dichotomy between the best grade 1 and everything else, as in "everything less than 1 means I'll start arguing with the teacher" - in which case I think one can make a convincing argument that the scale is in fact ordinal.

If your scores are truly interval, then you can try transforming either scores or class size to get a roughly linear relationship, then try [pearson-r](/questions/tagged/pearson-r).

If your scores are ordinal, or you simply can't get a linear relationship, try [spearman-rho](/questions/tagged/spearman-rho) or [kendall-tau](/questions/tagged/kendall-tau). I personally prefer Kendall's $\tau$, simply because I like the rationale with concordant and discordant pairs better, but to a degree, the choice between Spearman and Kendall is one of taste. Consider looking at our relevant question [Kendall Tau or Spearman's rho?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3943/1352) for inspiration.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Stephan Kolassa. I will try transforming my data to make it better fit a linear relationship.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer was helpful, please consider [upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and/or [accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.