# Difference between Spearman and Kendall-Tau correlation test

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

My question is not about the definition of the two rank correlation methods, but it is a more practical question: I have two variables, X and Y, and I calculate the rank correlation coefficient with the two approaches. With the Kendall-tau-b (which accounts for ties) I get tau = 0 and p-value = 1; with Spearman I get rho = -0.13 and p-value = 0.44.

Why does Kendall tell me there is exactly no correlation, while Spearman does see a nonzero correlation?

Comment: Spearman's rho and Kendall's tau are calculated in different ways. Why do you believe that something is going wrong with the Kendall tau calculation (and not the Spearman one)?

Comment: Because I get a P-value of 1... Is not that suspicious?

Comment: $p=1$ is a direct consequence of $\tau_b=0$, so the question is why $\tau_b=0$ and $\rho= -.13$ is a problem for you.

Comment: Then, I re-formulate my question: why according the Kendall-tau there is an exact no-correlation, while Spearman is less strict on that?

Comment: Thank you. That clarification makes for a much better question. I took the liberty of editing it into your post (and upvoting) and answering. Hope my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spearman's $\rho$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) and [Kendall's $\tau$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) are calculated differently. That is, they have different notions of "correlation". (As does [Pearson's $r$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).) Thus, they will output different correlation coefficients.

I don't see anything surprising about having one type of correlation zero and one nonzero.

Here is a fun little dataset with $\rho<0$, $r=0$ and $\tau>0$:

```
> xx <- 1:6
> yy <- c(-0.2,2.5,1,2,3.5,-1)
> plot(xx,yy,pch=19)
> cor(xx,yy,method="spearman")
[1] -0.02857143
> cor(xx,yy,method="kendall")
[1] 0.06666667
> cor(xx,yy,method="pearson")
[1] 1.748437e-18
```

[image: correlation example]

So different measures of correlation will output different results. Your next question probably is which coefficient you should use. Happily enough, we already have a question on this: [Kendall Tau or Spearman's rho?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3943/1352)