# Correlation between categorical data

Tags: regression, correlation, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I gave a questionary to 190 people to answer some questions. I want to check the correlation between the annual salary and how satisfy people are. So my two variables are **annual salary** and **satisfaction**. The data from annual salary are grouped into 6 categories: those without annual salary **0**, 1-10,000 **(10)**, 10,000-25,000 **(25)**, 25,000-50,000 **(50)** , 50,000-75,000 **(75)**, 75,000-100,000 **(100)** and above 100 **(200)**. The satisfaction takes values form 0 to 10 (10 is very satisfied). My advisor suggested to do a regression but I found the $R^2$ = 0.01. I also tried to make a scatter plot but the data look strange.

Could you please suggest how to find the correlation between these two variables?

I attach an example of my excel spreadsheet with the data.

[image]

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).  In this case, we refer you to post data in a computer-readable format, facilitating for people to use your data to  exemplify their answers!

Comment: You seem to have ordinal data, not categorical. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289066/ordinal-vs-ordinal-correlation-vs-significance

Comment: Why is it such a problem that you wound up with $R^2=0.01?$ This tells me that salary is a very weak predictor of satisfaction at work. I could believe that big earners are stressed and unhappy, not just thrilled to be making a lot of money (and the reverse for modest earners). I think your method of treating satisfaction as a numerical variable (instead of ordinal) is a mistake, but nothing says that salary has to be a good predictor of satisfaction.

Comment: Consider searching the site & reading some of the existing threads. How to assess the correlation between categorical variables has been covered several times.

Answer (score 0):

For categorical variables, you won't get a correlation coefficient per se, but there is a statistical test that will allow you to see if the two variables are independent, and in this case, you should use:
[Chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) of independence.

To get out of a value for how strong the association between the two variables is, you can use a [Cramér's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V)