# How to find out if there is any correlation between a yes/no question and Likert scale data?

Tags: logistic, correlation, categorical-data, ordinal-data, likert

I have used a survey to research willingness to pay regarding virtual goods in videogames. For this, I have asked the respondents a couple of questions via Likert scale, to get their opinions on certain statements. I then asked them if they had ever purchased virtual goods before.

In this case, I want to see if satisfaction with the game leads to a higher likeliness of purchasing virtual goods. How would I go about testing this statistically? My first idea was to convert my Likert data to numerical values, E. G. from strongly disagree = 1 to strongly agree = 5. However I can't seem to find which type of test I should use to then see if there is any correlation between a higher satisfaction value and buying virtual goods.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly disagree to strongly agree is ordinal data. There is a large set of methods to use with ordinal data: spearman correlation or Kendall's tau may be the most prominent ones.

Answer (score 1):

You could use logistic regression. If you represent your likert, that is ordinal, predictor with numerical codes $1,2, \dotsc$, then use also a quadratic term to represent possible nonlinearity in the effects, or maybe even with a spline.

For an example with a monotone spline, see [Looking for function to fit sigmoid-like curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206073/looking-for-function-to-fit-sigmoid-like-curve/316446#316446).  For some other ideas see [How do you estimate correlations between ordinal and binary data in SPSS?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38548/how-do-you-estimate-correlations-between-ordinal-and-binary-data-in-spss) and specifically [Correlations between continuous and categorical (nominal) variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables).

Comment: The problem I'm struggling with is that when I look at any of the tests online, people are always using two numeric variables. How would I go about calculating the Spearman coefficient for example, with Yes/No data?

Comment: You shouldn't use Spearman, read also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables

Comment: The spearman correlation function in base R is corrected for this, no?

Comment: Surely this is answering the inverse question: are people more likely to be satisfied with the game if they are willing to spend money in it?