# Most suitable method for checking the correlation between nominal and ordinal?

Tags: r, correlation, generalized-linear-model, ordinal-data

I would like to check the correlation between one nominal variable and another ordinal variable, is there any help about which method I can use? I used tau to check the correlation between two ordinal variables, was that correct?

Is spearman suitable?

Comment: I've voted to move this to [stats.se] since you're asking about stats methods rather than code, but I'm almost certain they'll want more detail and/or will tell you this has already been answered there

Comment: Are there more than two levels in the nominal variable ?

Comment: There are many posts here, probably a dup ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/correlation-coefficient-between-a-non-dichotomous-nominal-variable-and-a-numer  or    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38548/how-do-you-estimate-correlations-between-ordinal-and-binary-data-in-spss   Search this site!