# Requirements for the Pearson Correlation Coefficient

Tags: correlation, normality-assumption

I discovered the following content in an old discussion thread:"Normality is not required to calculate a Pearson correlation; it's just that some forms of inference about the corresponding population quantity are based on the normal assumptions (CIs and hypothesis tests)." ([How to choose between Pearson and Spearman correlation?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/how-to-choose-between-pearson-and-spearman-correlation))

Can anyone please advise on published literature confimring the above claims? I am assuming that in saying "Normality is not required to calculate a Pearson correlation", the contributor meant "Normality is not required to calculate a valid Pearson correlation coefficient."

Comment: Start with your favorite stats textbook.

Comment: I can't see that quotation on the linked thread.

Comment: Suppose $x$ is uniform discrete, $y = a + bx$ exactly and so $y$ is also uniform discrete. Correlation is thus $1$ or $-1$ -- and you would say it was _invalid_?