# Compare the consistensy of two ordinal variables

Tags: ordinal-data

I have have a dataset of about 500k subjects, each subject have 2 measures of the same thing:

measures A: in which 0 is the worst case and 1 is the best case.

measures B: in witch ordinal variable with values 0,1,2,3  in which 0 is the worst case and 4 is the best case.

I want check if the two measures are consistent witch each other, is there statistical procedure to do it?

Edit: by consistent I mean that people that are in the best case in the measure A tend to have higher values in the measure B, And people in the worst case in the measure A tend to have lower values in the measure B.

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent".

Comment: @Galen, thanks for the answer I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want some measure of correlation, this is what your definition of *consistency* measures. For comparing the most relevant alternatives, see [How to choose between Pearson and Spearman correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/how-to-choose-between-pearson-and-spearman-correlation)