Rank correlations: what is the difference between spearman coefficient and $R^2$?
When the data are not normal, how can the Spearman rank coefficient be interpreted differently from $R^2$?
As I understand it, when performing a rank correlation, the axes typically shouldn't show the actual raw data, but their ranks.
However, I found this paper, DOI: 10.1183/13993003.00092-2016, Here: https://erj.ersjournals.com/content/48/2/484.long
where the graphs display the actual data, not their ranks, with the Spearman coefficient and $R^2$ (Graph D), also when performing the Mann Whitney test (Graph C), the axes don't display the ranks, but the raw data:

What is it that I am not understanding correctly?

For a start Spearman correlation like almost any other correlation varies from $-1$ to $1$. That's isn't true of $R^2$ which cannot be negative.

The question in the title might be answered with https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/how-to-choose-between-pearson-and-spearman-correlation


As I understand it, when performing a rank correlation, the axes typically shouldn't show the actual raw data, but their ranks

The computation is done with the ranks, but it is fine to present the data in a raw format. It is even more desirable. People want to see the original data and how the measurements have been. The graph (d) shows a lot more information, like values and range of the data.
